# Path problem in URL ( absolute and relative )

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, path

I have a local website with "Nodejs" (using "Express" framework). I'm using express route for showing each file in my directory and if the file that requested isn't in my directory I want to render 
`not-found.html`. 
But I realized a weird things happen. 
Here it's the issue:

when user enter something like this: "http://localhost:3000/swgw" the last middleware execute and "not-found.html" render property. (with css style)
  when user enter URL like following pattern: "http://localhost:3000/products/*" the problem is this time `not-found.html` render without css style. (**Note:** * isn't 1-6)

- public

  - products

    - product-1.html
    - product-2.html
    - product-3.html
    - product-4.html
    - product-5.html
    - product-6.html
  - style

    - not-found.css
  - not-found.html
- server.js

  ***server.js***

  ````
  ```
  ...
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

  app.get("/products/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    // since I have six product with id from 1 to 6. 
    if (req.params.id <= 6 && req.params.id >= 1) {
      res.setHeader('content-type', 'text/html');
      return res.sendFile(path.resolve(`public/products/product-${req.params.id}.html`));
    }  
    else {
      next();
    }
  });

  app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.status(404);
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('public/not-found.html'));
  });
  ```
  ````

  ***not-found.html***
      
      `...
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/not-found.css" >
      ...`

Comment: Change to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/not-found.css" >`.  You want a path that is relative to the `public` directory that `express.static()` has as its root.

Comment: Thanks, my  problem solved. But may u please explain me in case `href="./style/not-found.css`  why it's works correctly when user enter : "http://localhost:3000/5" but not work on "http://localhost:3000/products/5" (I mean loading css successfully)

Comment: See the explanation I put into an answer below.

Comment: You seem to be serving static files only and that would be simpler to ditch your serveer code altogether and simply use [http-server](use https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/not-found.css" >.
```

You want a path that is relative to the public directory that `express.static()` has as its root.

> But may u please explain me in case href="./style/not-found.css" why it's works correctly when user enter : "localhost:3000/5" but not work on "localhost:3000/products/5" (I mean loading css successfully)

When the link your HTML page does not start with `http://` or with `/`, then it is considered a path-relative link and the browser will take the path of the page and combine it with the URL in the link to make a full URL before sending it to the server.  So, when you have this:

```
href="./style/not-found.css"
```

and the page URL is this:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/something
```

The browser will end up requesting:

```
http://localhost:3000/products/style/not-found.css
```

And, your server won't know what to do with that.  On the other hand, when you change the `<style>` tag to this:

```
 href="/style/not-found.css"
```

Then, your URL starts with a `/` so the only thing the browser will add to it is the domain and the browser will request:

```
http://localhost:3000/style/not-found.css
```

which will work.

So, when you use a path like:

http://localhost:3000/5

Then, the path for that is just `/` so when you combine `/` with `./style/not-found.css`, the browser will end up requesting

```
http://localhost:3000/stye/not-found.css
```

and it will work because the path was a root path.  So, it doesn't work for pages that are not at the top level.  This is why your static resource URLs should always be path absolute (start with a `/`) so they don't depend upon the path of the hosting page.

Comment: Thanks. I totally understood. Is it any useful article or course about designing route for nodeJS server  ? (Efficient way )                                                                                                And why some code uses different path for they static files . (May be because for example in route "/products" files in there have different css files? or images resource ?   )

Comment: @omid - It's possible to use all relative URLs on purpose for nested directories, but in practice, it is likely more trouble that it's worth.  You can still use an absolute and use different resources on a nested page just as easily and not run the risk of running into the problem you did.